# Why did Western Digital name their drives "Caviar"?

Tags: hardware, storage

I'm asking in Retrocomputing because the Caviar line of HDDs was released in the most recent era of retrocomputing.

Does anyone know why they named the line "Caviar"? Why do they associate Sturgeons eggs with reliable data storage?

Comment: Look 'caviar' up on Google first, otherwise the site becomes a first resort for information. You'll see it's a luxury food. You're saying you knew that it was a Sturgeon's egg, the obscurer fact, but not that it was a luxury?

Comment: It's like calling something the ['cadillac'](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cadillac), which seems to be a word that denotes quality to Americans, though it's difficult to understand why  :-)

Comment: @another-dave There was a time when Cadillac actually meant "best of the American made cars" **and** "America made the best cars". But it has been quite a while for Cadillac, and while Tesla is arguably making the best cars (in America or anywhere else), that is because of technology not luxury. But in any case, while colloquially "Cadillac" and "caviar" both alluded to "the best", "Cadillac" was already trademarked so "caviar" was the way to go.

Comment: @another-dave, "Luxury" and "quality" do not both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Caviar, as a word, is associated directly with luxury.  That's most likely what the marketing focus group were thinking when they put it forward as a possibility.  Most likely only one possibility of several, which were then selected by C-level executives.

Relatively few people know what the eggs actually taste like.